# Navigation Stack for only forward motion

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to implement the navigation stack only allowing forward motion on a differential drive robot?

The reason being that gmapping is sending reverse commands and I only have sensors on the front of the robot, therefore sometimes it reverses into things. Im using frontier exploration if that information is needed.

Also I suppose would frontier exploration need backwards motion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214115/navigation-stack-for-only-forward-motion/) by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Miguel,

I'll try to shed some light on this.

Obviously, you can implement the desired behaviour yourself. This would mean implementing a local planner following the 'nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner' interface (see the [nav_core documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core)).

`gmapping` is actually "just" doing map building, thus, it does not send any commands. `frontier_exploration` also just sends goals in terms of `geometry_msgs::PoseStamped` using the `move_base_msgs/MoveBaseAction` interface to the `move_base`node. `move_base` is actually the one creating the movement commands.

Thus, you would need to adapt the parameters of you local planner (and probably of you global planner) to achieve the respective behaviour.

Check out the [`move_base` documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) and especially the one for the [`dwa_local_planner`](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner).
I guess you can achieve what you want by setting the parameter `~<name>/min_vel_x` for the `dwa_local_planner`, if you have configured it as local planner in the `move_base`node. (I'm not sure, if this works for `base_local_planner` as well)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-20**:
Thank you, that makes sense, would it be a bad idea to do this for any reason?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-20**:
You mean only driving forwards? As long as the robot is able to turn on the spot, I don't see any drawback. Otherwise, you might get trapped.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-20**:
But turning on the spot would require one of the wheels to go backwards? Or will it just turn one wheel forward rather than one back and one forward?, Or is this separate from actually reversing?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-21**:
This actually depends on the robot you have. `move_base` has a `geometry_msgs::Twist` interface. It just sends velocities with respect to the `base_link` (usually). Thus, if it sends the command to turn, i.e. only rotational velocity, it depends of the controller of your robot what it actually does.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-21**:
Oh ok I understand, so the controller is the one who decides how to interpret the Twist message. Thanks for your help.